# Ansible: Status changed is always showed when I disable firewall

Tags: ansible, centos7, firewall

I try to disable the firewall on Centos7 using ansible.
This works:

```
  - name: turn off firewall for install
    command: systemctl disable firewalld
    become: yes
```

But I have to rerun this ansible playbook multiple times and everytime the output is showing "`changed`" while I would expect this to be "`ok`"?

```
TASK [turn off firewall for install] *******************************************
changed: [node1]
changed: [node2]
changed: [node3]
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [systemd](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/systemd_module.html) module instead of using `command` for example:

```
- name: turn off firewall for install
  systemd:
   name: firewalld
   state: stopped
   enabled: false
```

From [Overriding The Changed Result](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#overriding-the-changed-result):

> When a shell/command or other module runs it will typically report “changed” status based on whether it thinks it affected machine state.

To override the “changed” result such that it does not appear in report output or does not cause handlers to fire you could try something like this:

```
- name: turn off firewall for install
  command: systemctl disable firewalld
  become: yes
  changed_when: False
```